# TemplateSyntaxError Unused at end of if expression

Tags: python, django, if-statement, boolean

Django 1.6.   I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /docprofile/5/
Exception Value: Unused 'c.user_id' at end of if expression.
```

on line:

```
{% if c.user_id == like.user_id and c.doctor_id == like.doctor_id %}
```

I've the following code:

```
 {% for c in UGC %}

  {% if c.doctor_id == doctor.id  %}
  <div class="cmts">

    <h4>{{c.comment}}</h4>
    <h4>{{c.user_id}}</h4>
    <p>Waited less than {{c.time}} mins</p>
    <p class="timestamp">{{c.submitted_on}}</p>

  </div>

    {% if c.user_id == like.user_id and c.doctor_id == like.doctor_id %}
       <img class="thumbs" src="/static/meddy1/images/thumbsup.png">

    {% elif if c.user_id == dislike.user_id and c.doctor_id == dislike.doctor_id %}
       <img class="thumbs" src="/static/meddy1/images/thumbsdown.png">
    {% endif %} 

  {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}`enter code here`
```

What does it mean unused at end of if statement?

Comment: You've got `{% elif if ...}`. Remove the `if`.